# node-server-screenshot Not working on live ubundu server

Tags: php, node.js, electron

node-server-screenshot works perfectly in localserver. But it does not works on live server (ubundu).

In node-server-screenshot, That uses electron library. If there any dependencies in electron for ubundu server?

Below code working fine in localhost.

`server_screenshot.fromURL("https://google.com", "googletest.png", function(){ 
});`

It also doesn't throw any error in live

Answer (score 1):

Please try to do:

```
server_screenshot.fromURL("https://google.com", "googletest.png", function(error){
    if(error) console.log(error);
});
```

This should allow you to view the Error and debug your App further!

Comment: Can you try `server_screenshot.fromURL("https://google.com", "googletest.png", console.log);`

Comment: I tried the above code. It throws null in local and generate screenshot. But in live it stills doesn't throw any error and also doesn't create screenshot   **https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7inqr8g7xf94wx/screenshot.png?dl=0** This is the live server log screenshot

Comment: Does it do anything if you use
`server_screenshot.fromURL("https://google.com", "googletest.png", {show: false}, console.log);`

Comment: still it throws nothing